# Login system that checks out if the user already has an account. If they have one then they get to login, if they don't then they must try again

Tags: javascript

My overall problem is actually finding the values of the variables ''loginEmail'' and ''loginPass'' inside my ''arrayRegistros''. It only becomes TRUE when I write the email and password inside includes manually, however, it always ends up turning into FALSE when I use the variables themselves. I tried converting the variables into strings, then used document.getElementById alongside a few other ideas but until now, none of them completed the login system I had planned. The help I need is how one can find a certain variable's value/object, inside a certain array.

login(registro){

```
            this.arrayRegistros;
            var loginEmail = document.getElementById('userEmail'); 
            var loginPass =  document.getElementById('userPass');

            var contaEmail = this.arrayRegistros.some((loginEmail) => {
                return loginEmail.emailRegistro.includes(loginEmail)
            })
            var contaPass = this.arrayRegistros.some((loginPass) => {
                return loginPass.passRegistro.includes(loginPass)
            })
            
            console.log(contaEmail)
            console.log(contaPass)
            
        }
```

Comment: When/where is `this.arrayRegistros` populated? I see where it's declared(?) and then shortly after you're calling `some()` on it.

Comment: I hope you don’t plan to check the username and password  on the clientside for a real login system.

Answer (score 0):

you should get values from inputs like this:

```
const data = [
   {
     user : 'jhon',
     password : 'asdf123'
   },
    {
     user : 'bob',
     password : 'asdf124'
   }
 ]
const userName = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
const passWord= document.getElementById('userPassword').value;
const findUser = data.filter( item => item.user === userName && item.password === passWord);
if(findUser.length > 0){
  //user found
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner, but thank you a lot for your help. You and the other buddy have helped me a lot, now I'm on way of storing the user's information in a safer place. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @SonicPlays No matter,❤

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are naming the parameter on the `Array.prototype.some` function the same as the variable you want to check outside of the predicate scope.

Second, suposing that `this.arrayRegistros` is a array with objects with the keys `emailRegistro` and `passRegistro` containing strings, DOM Elements **CANNOT** match with strings, but a `element.value` can.

Another thing you should have in mind is that includes is not an equality operator, `'a-very-strong-password'.includes('a');` will return `true`.

And, last, you should never validate login and password on the browser, because the user can edit the JavaScript code on-the-fly and get to login without any real credential.

With that in mind, I think the solution would be something like that (ignoring the browser validation problem):

```js
const $userField = document.getElementById('userEmail');
const $passField = document.getElementById('userPass');

const registros = [
  {
    email: 'example@example.com',
    password: 'a-very-strong-password'
  },
  ...anotherUsers
]; 

function login(registro) {
  const { value: user } = $userField;
  const { value: pass } = $passField;
  
  // You can use `Array.prototype.some` to just know if the specific user credentials exist, or use `Array.prototype.find` to know if exist AND grab the user, to further utilization
  const item = registros.find(item => item.email === user && item.password === pass);

  if (item) {
    // User found
  } else {
    // User not found
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner, but thank you a lot for your help. You and the other buddy have helped me a lot, now I'm on way of storing the user's information in a safer place. Thank you a lot!